# Variable WHERE in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to list a simple query.

I have table `users` with the columns `name` and `payment` (which value can be `1` or `0`)

I want echo all and count how many have payment 0 and how many payment 1.

I don't know where put variable: `"WHERE payment = 1 or 2"`

```
$query=mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(*)) AS how, name FROM users WHERE category = "1" group by name');

    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo 'Company: '.$result['name'].' - payment0: ??? / payment1: ???<br>';
    }
```

**Example:**

```
name | payment

aaa 1

aaa 0

bbb 1

bbb 1

bbb 1
```

So result should be:

```
Company: aaa - payment0: 1, payment1: 1

Company: bbb - payment0: 0, payment1: 3
```

How do that in one question ?

Comment: What is payment number or text? May it have values 0/1 or 1/2? It's confusing in your question. As you want to aggregate different rows in different columns you will need to use subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, this is your answer:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(*)) AS how, name FROM users WHERE category = "1" AND payment IN (1,2) GROUP BY name');
```

Comment: $result['payment][1] ??

Answer (score 0):

As you want to summarize different rows in different columns (different columns are counted in payment0 than in payment1 of the same row) you need to use sub-queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    name, 
    q0.payment0 as payment0, 
    q1.payment1 as payment1 
FROM 
    users LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT name, COUNT(*) as payment0 
        FROM users WHERE category = 0 ) as q0 
        ON users.name = q0.name
    LEFT JOIN
        SELECT DISTINCT name, COUNT(*) as payment1 
        FROM usersWHERE category = 1 ) as q1 
        ON users.name = q1.name
```

Then fetching:

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo 'Company: '.$result['name'].' - payment0: ['payment0'] / payment1: ['payment1']<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you need is:

```
SELECT
    `name`,
    COUNT(IF(`payment` = 0, 1, 0)) AS `payment0`
    COUNT(IF(`payment` = 1, 1, 0)) AS `payment1`
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
    `category` = '1'
GROUP BY
    `name`
```